# Prevent ourselves from seeing messages

Tags: encryption, instant-messaging

#### Background

We are an API provider. We are unifying **3rd party messengers** where we can't control the client app.

#### What we need

Even though we need to provide the 3rd party messengers with the unencrypted message we would like to **prevent ourselves from reading the content** of messages sent via our API in both directions as much as possible.

#### The process of sending/receiving messages with 3rd parties

Sending a message to client have this process:

1. Client sends a message `{content: "Hello!"}` to us.
2. We will process the message.
3. We send it to a 3rd party.

#### Partial solution

I am not able to find a satisfiable solution but maybe I'm missing just a last piece. Messages in the logs and database will be encrypted. This a scenario I came up with:

1. Client sends an encrypted message `{content: "f8239jflads8"}`
2. We will process the message.
3. Just before sending to a 3rd party, we will **SOMEHOW GET THE KEY** and decrypt the message.
4. We will send the message `{content: "Hello!"}` to a 3rd party.

#### Questions

1. Is there another solution?
2. Is it possible to secure the decryption key so that users are safe OR at least safer? E.g. by limiting who can see the decryption keys so that nobody from our company can decrypt the messages from logs or database?

Comment: What about generating a client side key at each app startup. Messages are encrypted using this key, sent to your servers, Your servers get the key for a single use, you decrypt and send the plaintext to the 3d party service.
If your client's app crashes/restarts... the pending(unsent) messages  could not be sent.

Comment: *"... when we need decrepted text to be sent to the 3rd parties?"* - if this is an actual requirement that you need to decrypt the text then this collides with your requirement to have end-to-end encryption. Please explain if this is an actual requirement or that it is just a feature of your idea to implement the chat and that you would rather not have such decryption be done by your system (i.e. only encryption in sender and decryption in recipient but not in your forwarding system).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The client app will be for example a Facebook Messenger app installed on mobile. There is no way that clients can decrypt messages. For this very reason we need to send messages to Facebook API as plain text. I'm aware that it will **not** be an e2ee.

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri We don't have a client app. The 3rd parties like Facebook have it.  How would you pass the decryption key to our servers? By providing an API where we would ask for it? How can we do it so that it's not the infamous **security by obscurity**?

Comment: @Amio.io: *"I'm aware that it will __not be__ an e2ee."* - yet you claim differently in your question: *"Our chat __can be__ end-to-end-encrypted because we just pass messages between 2 users."* Maybe a typo?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry for confusion. **Chat** is one product that we can control completely. We provide an API and also a client. That's why I'm saying it can be e2ee. **3rd parties** like Facebook are just connector. We don't control the client application. If we want the end users to read plain text we also need to send them plain text to Facebook. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @Amio.io: I've deleted everything from your question regarding your own chat and its end-to-end encryption since this was completely irrelevant to what you actually wanted to know and just made the question very confusing.

Comment: Since your exposing "just" an API.. how a client can even send an encrypted message ?

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri First, thank you, for trying to understand and for your time!

End user of e.g. Facebook cannot. He just sends a plain text to Facebook. Facebook in turn deliveres us the plain text. Now, we'd like to encrypt it before it gets to database and to logs. Our client (not client app) will then via webhooks receive the encrypted messages which he will decrypt. 

Maybe the only way is to secure the encryption key on our side so that we can't abuse it? But how.

Comment: I think that what you are trying to do is impossible: you have in input and output cleartext messages, but you want to not be able to read them. At both ends you will be able to read them, whatever you do in between.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have the client app (which must already have the message in plaintext) send the message to the third party chat system directly instead of through your system. Depending on how you authenticate with the third party, this may mean that you'll have to disclose your API key to the client or provision a unique API key for each client users and somehow restrict their permissions.

Alternatively, if you authenticate with the third party app using an algorithm like HMAC, you may be able to split the HMAC calculation into two. The client app should calculate a hash of the plain text message, send the hash to your server, which should then calculate the authenticated hash from the given hash and your API signing key. The client then can make a connection to the third party server (possibly proxied through your server if there are IP address restrictions) and send the authenticated hash and the plaintext message using your credential without disclosing the content of the message to your server. This is a form of blind signing. However, you need to be careful with this as blind signing means that you also have no control over what you're signing and it may be possible for a malicious client to construct message that allows them to do things they shouldn't if your API signing key have greater privilege than what the client is supposed to have.

Comment: The best way for our customers would be if we made our solution on-premise (installed on their servers). It's what you describe in the 1st part but to the extreme. As to the 2nd part, unfortunately, it's not a solution for us because we need to decorate the data or use it for analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your client sends you:

```
{
   "content": "EncryptedMessage!",
   "defaultKey": {
   "passphrase": "DecryptionKey",
   "clientIdentifier":"clientIdKey"
  }
}
```

The `defaultKey` is something you can validate but you cannot determinate or guess, it's something unique that can be generated on install time, up to you to consider adding/implementing a `GenerateKeys()`, `Encrypt()` , `Decrypt()` functions.

All you have to do at this point is to process the `content` with `defaultKey.passphrase` before sending it back to a 3d party.

To keep logs, you can keep track (on db?) of `clientIdKey` and encrypted `content`. The `clientIdKey` is tied to a unique client and cannot be used to decrypt the `content`.

Comment: I like this idea a lot! :) The clients could encrypt every  `content` with a different key every time. We would not store the `passphrase` and would not log it either.

Comment: Nice to hear this :)

Comment: What's the point of sending the decryption key with the message itself? If you just want to log something to keep track of message sending, you can just hash the message then log the hash.

Comment: euh..maybe to decrypt the message before forwarding it to a 3d party ?